# "Unsupported axiom" when using Pellet Reasoner on AllegroGraph RDF Triple Store

Tags: rdf, triplestore, pellet, allegrograph

I created an RDF triple store in AllegroGraph. Now I want to run a reasoner on it using the Java API. I decided to use Pellet Reasoner ([download-link](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.github.ansell.pellet/pellet-common/2.3.2)). It works with the koala.owl ([link](https://github.com/pezra/pretty-printer/blob/master/Jenna-2.6.3/testing/ontology/bugs/koala.owl)).

When applying it to AllegroGraph triple store I get the following ERROR:

```
org.mindswap.pellet.jena.graph.loader.DefaultGraphLoader addUnsupportedFeature
WARNING: Unsupported axiom: Ignoring literal value used with ObjectProperty :
```

What is the problem?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

Actually I got the same problem with every triple in my database.
(All of the triples were created in TopBraid Composer.)

A few more examples:

```
WARNING: Unsupported axiom: Ignoring triple with unknown property from RDF 
namespace: owl:M80x2 @rdf:majorDiameterMax 
"79.96"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string



WARNING: Unsupported axiom: Ignoring triple with unknown term from OWL 
namespace: owl:1102 @rdf:type owl:Part


WARNING: Unsupported axiom: Ignoring literal value used with ObjectProperty : 
http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#FrenchFrancCoin 
@http://www.ontologyportal.org/SUMO.owl#externalImage 
"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/69/France_03.gif"^^xsd:anyURI

WARNING: Unsupported axiom: Ignoring triple with unknown term from OWL 
namespace: owl:SG_45 @rdf:type owl:Module
```

Comment: Isn't the message pretty clear: "Ignoring literal value used with ObjectProperty"? In OWL DL (what Pellet is reasoning with), it is not allowed to use literals with object properties. This means that you must not have a triple (*s*,*p*,*o*) where *p* is an object property and *o* is a literal, which you probably have in your triple store.

Comment: Antoine, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I get this WARNING for every triple in my triple store..I updated the post with a few more examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this warning because you are using literals as objects of triples that have an object property in the predicate position. When you write:

```
sumo:FrenchFrancCoin  sumo:externalImage  "http://..."^^xsd:anyURI .
```

you are saying that the external image of `sumo:FrenchFrancCoin` is the sequence of characters `h`, `t`, `t`, `p`, `:`, `/`, `/`, ... which is not an image. What you probably want to say is:

```
sumo:FrenchFrancCoin  sumo:externalImage  <http://...> .
```

that is, the image of `sumo:FrrenchFrancCoin` is the thing denoted by `<http://...>`, which is quite possibly an image, not a sequence of characters.

Furthermore, you are using IRIs having the `owl:` namespace to define classes and instances, which is not allowed by the OWL 2 specification. All IRIs that start with the `owl:` prefix are in the *reserved* vocabulary of OWL 2 DL (the logic that Pellet reasons with). You must not use the reserved vocabulary to define classes, individuals, properties, datatypes, or ontologies.